# Error while installing tide (Titanium Desktop)

Tags: html, css, web, tidesdk

I was installing TiDev Community-1.3.03.It then downloaded 2 packages and after downloading completed ,it gave me the following error

`Couldn't load file:/opt/titanium/runtime/linux/1.1.0/libkhost.so, error: libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

What should I do now?Please Help !
(i am using linux mint 15 cinnamon 32-bit)

Answer (score 0):

*No such file or directory* means that the file can not be found or not be opened (but I assume the first one).

- Check if that file is realy in that folder
- Check if you have a missspelling in the filename
- Check if your script has permission to open and read the file

Comment: Yes the `libkhost.so` file is there and the name is also correct,but there is no file named `libjpeg.so` in that folder.In fact I didn't do anything,it was just automatic installation

Comment: does your system meets the requirements for the installation? Are all libraries installed that TiDev relies on?

Comment: Sorry,but I don't know about this.Actually I download TiDev Community for linuxfrom here:`http://api.appcelerator.net/p/pages/app_page?token=m4rZLSv6` and then executed `TiDev Community` and then it downloaded 2 packages nearly 30MB and then the error.I am a newbie to TiDev